# Minimize the maximum difference between the towers recursively

Tags: java, recursion

Given heights of n towers and a value k. We need to either increase or decrease height of every tower by k (only once) where k > 0. The task is to minimize the difference between the heights of the longest and the shortest tower after modifications, and output this difference.

Input {1, 5, 15, 10}

K = 3

Output is 8

Input {1, 10, 14, 14, 14, 15}

K = 6

Output is 5

I realized this can be solved with DP technique / Greedy technique.  Can anyone help me solve this through **recursion**.  A sample code snippet below.  Thanks in anticipation for the response.

```
public class TowerHeights {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] towerHeight = {1,5,15,10};
        int k = 3;
        Arrays.sort(towerHeight);
        int min = towerHeight[0] + k;
        int max = towerHeight[towerHeight.length-1] - k;
        minimize(towerHeight,1,k,min,max);
    }

    public static void minimize(int[] towerHeight, int index, int k, int min, int max){
        if(index<=towerHeight.length-2){

            //I need help in completing this function recursively
        }
    }
}
```

Question Reference:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimize-the-maximum-difference-between-the-heights/

Comment: `I realized this can be solved with DP technique / Greedy technique.` - Post your DP technique / Greedy technique.

Comment: Why do you think this is a recursive problem?  `max - min` in your `main` function will already give you the answer.  While you *could* use recursion to find your minimum and maximum, it seems to add little.

Comment: Can you define the problem a bit better? Increaseng or decreasing every tower does not change anything in the difference since you can not have negative heights...

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci: It seems likely that it's asking about this: by increasing the minimum of `1` by `3` and decreasing the maximum of `15` by `3`, we get the required `(15 - 3) - (1 + 3) == 8`, but there is nothing recursive in that, unless you want to use recursion to find the max/min.

Comment: @ScottSauyet - I am learning and trying to solve this through recursion.  Just for learning trying to solve this via recursion.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash - I saw this question in geekforgeek and dp / greedy technique is there.  But I am particular in solving this problem through recursion.

Comment: @all After going through this webinar I am motivated to solve this through recursion. https://youtu.be/y7Vxo_DBC2E?t=3541

Comment: @ScottSauyet - You can please take a look at above youtube url to get what I am looking for.

Comment: We need to either increase or decrease height of every tower by k (only once) where k > 0. does not say that you can choose to increase the minimum and decrease the maximum. :)

Comment: @ArmandoBallaci - Yes by doing so, you need to minimize the maximum difference between the values in array.  For ex.  first sort the given array.  [1,5,10,15].  Then increase k on first and decrease k on last.  so [4,5,10,12].  you need to apply these rules to all the elements in the array and again sort the array.  Then find the minimum difference between the maximum and minimum towers.  Hope you understood the question.

Comment: "...please take a look at above youtube url to get what I am looking for."  That's not a reasonable request, questions here are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: @pjs - I agree with you.  The question is very clear already.  In case for further clarification, I have given the link for reference.

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan If people are asking for clarification and you think watching the video will clarify for them, perhaps your question is not as clear as you seem to think it is.  What is the essence of the video that you think makes it worth referring people to?

Comment: @pjs, Sir, I copied the question from geekforgeek and trying to solve it recursively.  You can go through the conversation once again.  I myself mentioned the youtube link just to be clear why I am trying to solve it recursively.  I didn't replied youtube link for clarification.  You can also see my above comments clarifying the doubts on questions asked.  I clearly understand what you mean.  Pls don't misunderstand.

Comment: @VigneshGopalakrishnan: Please edit to include a link to the site where you found this and add enough examples to make it clear why this is not the trivial problem others including myself thought it was.  Suggestion: before posting a question, re-read to see if it contains enough information who's never seen the issue before to understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a problem for DP or subproblem of greedy I think. To solve recursively try this way, like do looping using recursion

```
public static int minimize(int[] towerHeight, int index, int k, int min, int max){
    if(index<=towerHeight.length-2){
        int subtract = towerHeight[index] - k; 
        int add = towerHeight[index] + k; 
        if (!(subtract >= min || add <= max)){
             if (max - subtract <= add - min) min = subtract; 
             else max = add;
        }
        return Math.min(minimize(towerHeight,index+1,k,min,max), max - min);
    }
    else {
        return max-min;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This is what I was looking for.  I'll try apply DP / Greedy techniques on top of it.  Thanks again.